Не корректно работает Fancybox 5
Всем доброго времени суток!
Перечитал очень много тем, по 5 раз обошёл документацию, но в чём причина понять не могу.
Пришёл клиент, попросил добавить галерею к слайдеру. Делал это несколько десятков раз на разных проектах - проблем не было. А тут не могу понять в чём дело.
Проблема заключается в том, что при открытии fancybox не подгружается основное изображение, выдаёт ошибку Image not found. При этом изображения для превьюшек - грузятся. Далее - если совершить 8-10 переходов по изображениям внутри галереи - они начинают отображаться, но у родительских элементов остаётся класс has-error. В консоли есть жёлтые предупреждения, но на проблему не влияют.
Пробовал:

Менять параметры и способы инициализации
Менять отображение элементов галереи
Вставлять все изображения jpg
Отключать другие скрипты, которые есть на сайте
Менять очерёдность подключения скриптов
Заводить не песочнице (всё работает отлично)

Сайт тут
Галерей несколько, выглядят так:


  //...Вызов
    triggerLink.click();
  //...

  Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox]', {
            
    Thumbs: {
      type: "classic",
    },

    on: {
      "Carousel.change": (fancybox) => {
        //Тут код для синхронизации со swiper
      },
    },
  });
<div class="portfolio__gallery" data-filter="2d">
  <a 
    href="https://bus.studio/assets/template/image/vd.jpg" 
    class="portfolio__gallery-wrap" 
    data-title="V&amp;D" 
    data-fancybox="portfolio-gallery-1" 
    data-filter="2d">
  </a>
  <a 
    href="https://bus.studio/assets/template/image/demon-hanters.jpg" 
    class="portfolio__gallery-wrap" 
    data-title="Охотники на демонов" 
    data-fancybox="portfolio-gallery-1" 
    data-filter="2d">
  </a>
  <a 
    href="https://bus.studio/assets/template/image/van-helsing.jpg" 
    class="portfolio__gallery-wrap" 
    data-title="Ван Хельсинг" 
    data-fancybox="portfolio-gallery-1" 
    data-filter="2d">
  </a>
</div>



Пожалуйста, помогите.

Похоже вы уже разобрались, на сайте вижу все работает. Вопрос неактуален?
